# How do you complete the Team Fortress 2 "Line Them Up" challenge?

Tags: hero-academy

I know this challenge must be solvable, but it seems impossible to me at this moment, since no matter what I do, it takes 3 actions to defeat the first three wizards (with the Heavy, or with the Medic boosting the Demoman) and 3 actions to defeat the last three wizards (by moving the Heavy over and attacking twice).

How do you complete this challenge?

[image: Line Them Up]

Comment: Was gonna say... that tag made me do a double-take.

Comment: It doesn't tell you this but the Demoman gets an AP when he stomps an enemy. That should help you solve it.

Comment: @Patrick - that's actually the TF2 team ability - all their units get an AP when they stomp an enemy.  Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the heavy and shoot the first mage, then the second, then the third mage. Select the demoman and step on the second mages body. Choose the demoman again and walk one spot further. Lob a grenade at the last Mage, then the Mage in front of him

Answer (score 4):

None of the other answers are correct, they all leave one Wizard left alive with 20 HP, thus failing the challenge. Here is the correct solution:

1. Attack the 2nd Wizard from the left with your Heavy.
2. Attack the 3rd Wizard from the left with your Heavy. (3rd Wizard dies)
3. Attack the 1st Wizard from the left with your Demoman. (1st/2nd Wizard dies)
4. Move your Demoman up two spaces.
5. Move your Demoman right one space.
6. Attack the 6th Wizard from the left with your Demoman.
7. Attack the 5th Wizard from the left with your Demoman. (4th/5th/6th Wizard dies)

Voila. You have completed the challenge. Cheers!

Comment: If I follow the steps in the accepted answer (or in your answer), I am able to complete the challenge, so there are multiple ways to finish it.  The two key points are that the Heavy must attack a different wizard each time (in order to take out the first 3 or 4) and the Demoman must move up and over, gaining extra APs in order to finish off the last 2 or 3 wizards.

Answer (score 2):

Kill the 3 first using the machinegun guy then use the bomber on last 3. You dont need to use the item. Trick is you point at different mages using the gunner. Hope this helps!

Comment: While this is correct, the "trick" is actually that you need to use an undocumented ability of the demoman in order to finish this.

Comment: @Bobson - gaining an AP when stomping is the TF2 team ability and it is documented: http://www.robotentertainment.com/games/heroacademy/webgameguide#tf2

Comment: @JasonBerkan - I actually just came across that about 10 minutes ago.  But it's impossible to find that out from within the app, since the TF2 team isn't on the team list, and you don't have a portrait to click on to get team info in the challenges.

Answer (score 0):

Attack first mage with heavy, then the second, then the third. Move heavy to the mage ( you gain ap), then move heavy to two living mages. Heavy does 200 physical damage up close, killing the first of two living mages. Move heavy to the last mage (you gain ap). Again heavy does 200 damage and viola, heavy one man army.